# How to request Steam API over 10000 times with PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, api

I need to call Steam market API over 10000 request for all items price. And I want to save them in my MySQL database. But my request is always crash. Is there any way to call API for too much request?

```
 file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=$marketHashName")
```

Example:

> http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=Dragonclaw%20Hook

Comment: 10,000 requests is 10,000 requests, and unless you can find some way to avoid making so many in the first place (like some sort of bulk API; try checking if one exists), that’s going to be a lot of requests no matter how you cut it. If it turns out you really need those 10,000 requests, you might start by adding delays between each request and putting the whole process in the background.

Comment: you should increase max execution time of your php because 10000 requests gonna take some good time no matter how fast your server is.

Comment: "Request is always crash". Can you be more specific about that?

Comment: It's never arrive to the end. It very long time for execution. And I don't know how can i split with ajax or something. I need sample code.

Comment: Is there any more code involved that might help to spot the problem? If the API itself returns an error, why not check for that?

Answer (score 10):

The Steam API is limited to [100,000 requests per day](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apiterms) -- whether a day is within a 24 hour period or based on calendar day isn't exactly clear.  I've made thousands of requests from the same IP address without any problems in the past.

Are you getting a 403 response code?  If so, you might be hitting the rate limit.  I would also be surprised if using multiple IP addresses will help since the rate limit is probably associated with your API key.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but since I'm doing some research including Steam for work, I guess this could help some people.

First off, the way we handle a lot of requests is by starting (in your case 10,000) processes which call the requests and use the data - delayed by 100ms, because else our database won't be able to complete all commands and it will mess with the saved data. I don't know if you could send all those requests without delay.

Second, the limit **is** per calendar days. You can send 100,000 requests on one day and another 100,000 from midnight on.

Another point is, that I have no idea what happens when you send more than 100,000 requests. So be careful with that.

Answer (score -1):

You basically need to split your request into multiple requests via different IP addresses, instead of 1 IP sending 10,000 requests. It should be for example, 10 IPs sending 1000 requests with around 500ms between each request. otherwise steam/Akamai will just ban your IP for flooding or ddos attempt. Again, 10,000 requests is a lot of requests, you will require better/more infrastructure to even attempt to do this effectively.

Comment: Don't get caught with that approach of using multiple IPs. If the API terms tell you that you may use 100,000 calls per API key per day, that's it. Cheating around might get you banned from using the API