# Trying to make around 1500 requests to steam store in one go

Tags: php, file-get-contents, steam-web-api

I want to save around 1500 json files per day from steam store on my server but the following code isn´t good enough.
As you can see below, I set it to sleep 2 seconds after saving each file to avoid getting my IP banned. But I can see that it was downloaded a total of 447 json files during period of 23 minutes

```
    if(get_http_response_code("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=".$steamappid) != "200"){
        sleep(2);
    } else {
        sleep(2);
        $content = file_get_contents("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=".$steamappid);
        if ($content != "") {
        $file = "/home/me/website.com/prices/".$steamappid.".json";
        $fr   = fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite($fr, $content . "\n");
        fclose($fr);
        }
    }
```

So basically I was wondering what could I do differently to make sure it downloads the rest of the files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340334/how-to-request-steam-api-over-10000-times-with-php-or-javascript may have some more information (although it seems more about the rate of requests than particular code fixes).

Comment: What's the exact problem? If you want this to work faster, why not remove the `sleep`  calls?

Comment: @NicoHaase if I remove sleep calls then I'm afraid I could be banned for doing too many requests too quickly (I know they have a limit of 10k requests per day but not sure if there are others per hour or minute).  

The problem is that currently it stop downloading the files after 450 requests or so and I need to do 1500 per day

Comment: Then why not do that with a proper queue? Use a database to store all information, then select some items (like 50 in one execution), starting with those not having any data or being the oldest, update these, stop the whole process and run another execution some minutes later

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sleep()` command is not a reliable way to throttle execution. I would advise to use a dedicated dependency that handles the [rate limiting](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/rate-limiting-a0783293026a) for you.

I am not that experienced in the PHP ecosystem but something like [Stiphle](https://github.com/davedevelopment/stiphle) is just what you need. I use a similar dependency in my Node.js projects.

```
/**
 * Throttle to 1500 per *rolling* 24 hours, e.g. the counter will not reset at
 * midnight
 */
$throttle = new Stiphle\Throttle\LeakyBucket;
$throttle->throttle('YOUR_STEAM_REQUEST_METHOD', 1500, 86400000);
```